# Random bump of a question? Is this a bug?

Tags: discussion, bumping, community-user

I saw a question this afternoon: [minimizing the norm of a curl over a domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44118)

Then I went on to cook up an answer. After I submitted, I was about to edit OP's question to make it better formatted. Suddenly I realized the question was asked two years ago... and I saw no other activities except my newly added answer.

Is this a bug in the system?

Comment: In this case, the bot's bumping served its intended purpose: the question got *your* attention, and you then proceeded to answer it. Worked all splendidly, I'd say.

Comment: @Ｊ.M. Hmm...I am curious what data mining algorithm the SE bot is using. After seeing your comment I search the MSE a bit and found many un-answered question or answered-but-not-accepted question. Why the bot decides to bump this question but not some other one?

Comment: Not sure either, but questions that are candidates for bot-bumping have to be at least a month old, and haven't had answers that are either accepted or upvoted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The other answer has no upvotes. This means that it is likely a Community user bump.

This sort of thing occurs from time to time to questions without upvoted answers, at least if the question's score is nonnegative.

How often exactly is a trade secret, I believe, but it's very normal to see these things happen.

Comment: I see. Thanks man!

Comment: To complete this, questions are also bumped when a deleted answer is edited (for <10k, this appears like nothing happened).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Not true, deletion and undeletion do not bump; re-opening a question does bump it though.

Comment: @Asaf You're right, I've checked on MSO and replaced with the likely accurate alternative I have observed a lot.